# How do you stop a looping Keynote presentation on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, keynote

I made a presentation in Keynote, looped it so as to share locally. Now I want to send it to friends, but I cant figure out how to stop the looping to get the share button back?

Answer (score 2):

Pinch out to exit (zoom out gesture).